# why this printf statement in the last of function is Not getting printed?

Tags: c, linked-list

I wrote a simple algorithm to detect loop in a singly  linked list,it worked correctly for a looped list. But in case of list with no Loop, After executing while loop, `printf` function is not printing in last statement of given code.

**This is a part of code:-**

```
   //Detacting a loop in singally linked list Using Fast(2x) and Slow (1x) traversal;
    void DetactLoop(struct Node **head)
    {
        struct Node *Fast = *head;
        struct Node *Slow = *head;
        if (Fast == NULL)
        {
            printf("Head is NULL");
            return;
        }
        while (Fast != NULL || Fast->next != NULL)
        {
            Fast = Fast->next->next;
            Slow = Slow->next;
            if (Fast == Slow)
            {
                printf("Loop detected!");
                return;
            }
        }
        printf("No Loop found!");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The loop `while (Fast != NULL || Fast->next != NULL)` will continue when `Fast` is not `NULL` and `Fast->next` is `NULL`. Then `NULL` is dereferenced at `Fast = Fast->next->next;` and an *undefined behavior* is invoked, typically leading to Segmentation Fault.

The loop should be `while (Fast != NULL && Fast->next != NULL)`. You should use AND, not OR.

Comment: Thank you for figuring out my stupidity,now it is working  and i understud why it did'nt.